# optaplanner stack overflow exception when saving planing result

Tags: xstream, optaplanner

when I try to save planing vehicle routing result for 665 customers (using "Save as.. " button) I get stack-overflow exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.isImmutableValueType(MapperWrapper.java:42)
```

with 10 (or more) customers less (655 or less) it is working properly. Any ideas what is wrong

the exception looks different in different casees, at first I tought it is some wierd character (which drives xml serialization crazy - as it was xml serialization methods on call stack), so I replaced all adresses with ids. than I tought that it is maybe if the adresses in nodes area do not have uniqe name - but that was not the case. I also tried 32 and 64 bit java but that did not help eather.

complete stack of last attempt is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10874009/stack-overflow-exception.txt
and this is zip of my vrp file, exception is 100% repordoucable with thid data set https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10874009/generated-n666-k36.zip

I am using binaries from : optaplanner-distribution-6.4.0.Final
thanks in advance

Comment: What's the xstream version in your classpath?

Comment: it is optaplanner - distribution version 6.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the VRP dataset becomes a certain size, the linked list structure triggers  a stackoverflow in XStream. At that size the XML format becomes very verbose too: for example 10k customers in XML format can take GB's of disk space... Best to export as a txt format when persisting big cases to disk (or store them in a database). See `VehicleRoutingSolutionFileIO`.

Comment: can I do any of that through optaplanner UI or configuration,  or do I have to use code  to use this options? thanks

Comment: i Managed to solve the issue by using option  -Xss256m  however size of XML file is 3 GB. so I guess I will have to use the options you mentioned. Only question is still if this has to be done in code (I have not been coding in java for years now, but it it seams I will start again :), or can I configure it somehow?

Comment: There is no VehicleRoutingExporter (yet?), but look at `TspExporter` for inspiration. Especially look at the `writeSolution()` method.